# How do I ensure an array has no null values?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I would like test my Array (input value) before submit my form.

My array with value :

```
const fields = [
  this.state.workshopSelected,
  this.state.countrySelected,
  this.state.productionTypeSelected,
  this.state.numEmployeesSelected,
  this.state.startAt
];
```

I've try this :

```
_.forEach(fields, (field) => {
  if (field === null) {
    return false;
  }
});

alert('Can submit !');
...
```

I think my problem is because i don't use Promise. I've try to test with `Promise.all(fields).then(());`, but i'm always in `then`.

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with asynchrony or promises.

Comment: @Bergi: The OP is using [lodash's `_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach), not Array's. It does indeed allow early termination via `return false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Still, `_.forEach` doesn't return a value or break from the function (to prevent the alert) like the OP expects, does it?

Comment: @Bergi: It does break the `_.forEach`. It doesn't return that information, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even though you're terminating the [lodash `_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) loop early, you don't do anything *else* with the information that you had a `null` entry.

Instead of lodash's `_.forEach`, I'd use the built-in [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (fairly new) or [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find out if any of the entries is `null`:

```
if (fields.includes(null)) { // or if (fields.indexOf(null) != -1)
    // At least one was null
} else {
    // All were non-null
    alert('Can submit !');
}
```

For more complex tests, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which lets you provide a callback for the test.

Live example with `indexOf`:

```js
const state = {
  workshopSelected: [],
  countrySelected: [],
  productionTypeSelected: [],
  numEmployeesSelected: [],
  startAt: []
};
const fields = [
  state.workshopSelected,
  state.countrySelected,
  state.productionTypeSelected,
  state.numEmployeesSelected,
  state.startAt
];
if (fields.indexOf(null) != -1) {
  console.log("Before: At least one was null");
} else {
  console.log("Before: None were null");
}
fields[2] = null;
if (fields.indexOf(null) != -1) {
  console.log("After: At least one was null");
} else {
  console.log("After: None were null");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, i've edit my code and it work nice, and very good explanation. Thank again !

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use promises unless there is an asynchronous operation (for example if you are getting that array from your server).

If you already have that array you can do something like:

```js
// Using lodash/underscore
var isValid = _.every(fields, (field) => (field!==null)}

// OR using the Array.every method

var isValid = fields.every((field)=>(field!==null))

// Or using vanilla JS only
function checkArray(array){
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length ; i ++){
       if(array[i]===null){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}

var isValid = checkArray(fields);

// After you get that value, you can execute your alert based on it
if(!isValid){
    alert('Something went wrong..');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple snippet

```
var isAllowedToSubmit = true;
_.forEach(fields, (field) => {
  if (!field) {
    isAllowedToSubmit = false;
  }
});

if(isAllowedToSubmit)
 alert('Can submit !');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without library:

```
if (fields.some(field => field === null)) {
    alert('Cannot submit');
} else {
    alert('Can submit');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use lodash, you can do this in simple vanilla javascript. Simply iterate over each field and if an error occurs set your `errors` bool to `true`

```
let errors = false;
fields.forEach(field) => {
  if(field === null || field === '') {
    errors = true;
  }
});

if (!errors) {
  alert('Yay no errors, now you can submit');
}
```

For an es6 you can use.

```
 const hasNoError = fields.every((field, index, selfArray) => field !== null);
 if (!hasNoError) {
    alert('yay It works');
 };
```

Have a look at Array.every documentation [Array every MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: It works, `field === ''` was added in place if the OP wanted to check any empty values in his/her array. I am not sure why I was down voted. This approach is better then using lodash.